# How are function name abbreviations of a chip conceived?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, connector, schematics

The microcontroller on the Arduino has functions such as RXD, XTAL1, ADC4, AVCC, MISO. These abbreviations are quite commonly used, and often make sense on first sight. One thing I noticed, that it's not just "first letters of each word":

- XTAL1: Crystal 1 input
- MISO: Master Input, Slave Output of the Serial Peripheral Interface
- AVCC: Voltage supply for analog digital converter
- RXD: UART receive input

How are these names conceived? Is there a guideline somewhere that I can follow for my own designs?

Comment: People think about things, try them out, and if they are good and well received they stick... Often it is just the starting letters of the involved words

Comment: You can look for a pattern as much as you want, but these abbreviations were coined by us humans. We got human error, some randomness and randomly shorten words as we want them. It's as if you want to see a pattern in slang words. You won't.

Comment: *Is there a guideline somewhere* No there isn't, if you want to call your pin *pinwithadifficulttoremebername1* then you can but you will get frowned upon. It just makes sense to follow the **unwritten rules** set by other ICs. If we all stick to similar names then life becomes easier to all of us. This has been done since ICs have existed so it is nothing new.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie LOL and the symbol would take up a whole page. Which is after all, the prime reason for abbreviating them in the first place.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It's those "unwritten rules" you talk about that I'm after. Could you write them down?

Comment: *Could you write them down?* Nope because then they would no longer be "unwritten rules". And if you look at the pin names on a few datasheets of well known ICs you'll quickly understand those rules yourself.

Answer (score 6):

If you just do first letter of each word, you usually end up with a) non-unique identifiers and b) non-informative names. From your examples:

- XTAL1: Difficult to use C for "crystal" as it's more widely used for capacitor. X is possibly from the Greek abbreviation of Christ (X), so ChrisTAL. [see comments]
- MISO: Describes the direction for each device, which can be ambiguous otherwise.
- AVCC: Analog, VCC. VCC comes from V-Collector-Collector from (older) bipolar devices where the collector is usually at the highest voltage.
- RXD: RX is a very common abbreviation for receive. RXD is then Receive Data.

In your own designs, as long as it's documented and provides some guidance as to what the pin does, it's fine. If it's been done before in another design, keep using it. It'll make your designs easier to understand for you and others. As the comments say, there's nothing particularly special but I think it helps to have consistency and some guidance for a knowledgeable reader.

Comment: I don't think "xtal" comes from "criss-cross". The source is rather older. In Greek, "Christ" is spelled as "Χριστός", which is often abbreviated to just "X". "Xtal" comes from applying the same abbreviation to the "Christ" part of "crystal" (even though they're not etymologically related, and the Greek word for "crystal" doesn't even start with a Chi. If you want to get technical, I suppose the abbreviation should really be "Xal", but that doesn't seem to have caught on.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Excellent, I'll add it to the answer, thanks :) My Classics is clearly weak...

Comment: @JerryCoffin see also my comment to the answer of DaveTweed. You beat me by a couple of minutes, while I wasn't watching other comments! :-)

Comment: RXD/TXD: I'm quite sure the "D" stands for "data", not "device".

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I was always taught device, but everyone else has said data so I'll go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They are mostly historical/traditional, rather than strictly logical. Except for MISO, these date from long before the development of integrated circuits.

- XTAL - This is just my guess, but in Britain, "X" is frequently pronounced "cross". So, "XTAL" becomes "cross-tal", a close approximation to "crystal".
- AVCC - V<sub>CC</sub> is the conventional way to denote the collector supply voltage in a BJT circuit, and is frequently also used in MOSFET circuits instead of the slightly more correct V<sub>DD</sub>. So this is just short for "analog supply voltage".
- RXD - Rx and Tx are traditional abbreviations for receive and transmit, so this is just "receive data". Note that depending on context, this could be either an input or an output of a particular circuit.

Sometimes the abbreviations become a little more obscure when details such as lower case and subscripts are lost to the limitations of ASCII strings.

Comment: "X" also represent Christ in Christian tradition (the Cross), so it is common abbreviation for the word Christ. Example: Xmas instead of Christmas. So it is more "Christ-tal", than "Cross-tal". And the pronounciation matches better.

Answer (score 1):

On addition to the other great answers given here, you have to understand that devices are developed on the shoulders of the previous art.

If you are developing a new micro, and are including the functionality of a UART or other well developed technology, you give the pins the same name as what it connects to or whatever previous state of the art used. Having the RS232 line called RXD and naming your pin SIP ("Serial input pin") would just confuse people. So you go with what folks know. As such, over the years, an informal standard has evolved.

Other pins that are specific to your device, or schematic come to that, you generally name with as few characters as you can while still portraying the function of the pin as best you can. The fact that you need to be able to fit all these names onto a symbol on your schematic dictates that long names are out.

It is also important to be careful not to use names that can be easily confused, for example. A pin named "Drive_A" could be an output or an input. If it's an input and there is a complimentary pin named "A_Drive" you can see that remembering which is which might cause a bit of confusion.